# what does value error in django refers , i am stuck

Tags: python, django, database, backend

```
#ValueError: "<Profile: Profile object (None)>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

what is value error why am i getting these ,
ValueError at /admin/profiles/profile/add/
"<Profile: Profile object (None)>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
# Create your models here.
from . utils  import get_random_code

class Profile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(default="no bio...", max_length=300)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(default='avatar.png', upload_to='avatars/')
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='friends')
    slug =    models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    

    def save(self, *args  ,**kwargs):
        ex = False
        if  self.first_name and self.last_name:
            to_slug =slugify(str(self.first_name ) + "" + str(self.last_name))
            ex = Profile.objects.filter(slug =to_slug).exists()
            while ex:
                to_slug = slugify(to_slug+""+str(get_random_code())) 
                ex = Profile.objects.filter(slug=to_slug).exists()
        else:
                to_slug = str(self.user)
                self.slug=to_slug
                super().save(*args ,**kwargs)

#`enter code here`utlis.py file
import uuid

def get_random_code():
    code = str(uuid.uuid4())[:8].replace('-', '').lower()
    return code
```

Comment: Try to put 'null=True' on your friends field

Comment: STILL getting same error after i put'null=True' any idea what went wrong here!

Comment: The problem is with your pk, idk why this is happening but if every User will have just one Profile you can make taht OneToOneField the Profile primary_key and this can work.

Comment: means?? 
this is confusing ??